# Rewrite Rule & Regex - Extract 'cat-name' and 'page-number' from http://domain.com/custom-post-type/category/cat-name/page/page-number

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules, regex

I have an URL formatted so:

`http://domain.com/custom-post-type/category/cat-name/page/page-number`

I need to extract:

`cat-name` and `page-number`

So that in my `functions.php`, I can create the custom rewrite rule:

```
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
  $newrules = array();
  $newrules['projects/category/(.+)/page/(\d+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=project&project_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
  return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

I am trying to use the expression:

`projects/category/(.+)/page/(\d+)/?$`

Which seems to work appropriately (escaping the forward slashes) in this example: http://rubular.com/r/5rzECsTexy

However, this never seems to work, the URL:

`http://domain.com/projects/category/print` and `http://domain.com/projects/category/print/page/2` always seem to 404.

My previous rewrite rule of `projects/category/(.*/?)$` worked for the category, but did not pull the page number properly.

**Edit**
Custom Post Type registration code (in my theme's `function.php`)

```
// Custom Post Types
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'project',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom rewrite rule to handle this, just set your taxonomy rewrite slug like:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'projects/category/%project_cat%' )
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Is there a reason not to use rewrite rules, or maybe a reason why this suggestion didn't work?

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules after switching? Maybe add your post type and taxonomy registration code to your question. It's easier to let WordPress automatically generate the rules, it takes care of both versions with/without pagination, and just keeps the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yes I flushed the rewrite rules biter switching. I'll add the post type registration code to the question! I ended up using custom queries and rewrite codes after finding the default setup didn't handle the taxonomy (categories) or pagination properly in the archives.

Comment: I see, you're using the built in category taxonomy and not a *custom* taxonomy. In that case, you need to change category base in `Settings > Permalinks` to `projects/category`. As for why they all seem to 404, that's an entirely different issue specific to built in taxonomies that has nothing to do with rewrites- by default those queries don't include custom post types. [See this answer for the solution to that](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47083/4771).