# category page for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I know this question has been asked a thousand times, but feel like I've looked at every single article on this issue, and none of them have worked for me.

All I want is for there to be a category page for my custom post type, products. So that I can type www.mysite.com/products and see all the products. Or if it's easier make it work like regular posts do www.mysite.com/category/products. Either works for me.

I have written the code in functions.php and also used plugins like CPT-onomy and CPT-UI to successfully make the custom post types and taxonomies. But this doesn't create the category page.

How is this accomplished? Please include instructions on permalinks if that is relevant to my situation too.

Here is the code I placed in functions.php. The second block that deals with taxonomies actually breaks the site. However, using the two plugins mentioned above, I've been able to successfully create taxonomies, but still can't get a category page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
        )
    );
}


function my_taxonomies_product() {
    $args = array();
    register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product' $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
```

updated code

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function my_taxonomies_product() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'type',
        'with_front' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
```

Comment: add your post type and taxonomy registration code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your taxonomy code has a missing comma before `$args` which is causing a fatal error:

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', $args );
```

[Enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) while working on code to see PHP errors, which would reveal the line number and error.

As for your post type, you have a page where you can view all products, which is the post type archive. This argument in your post type registration code enables that:

```
'has_archive' => true
```

But since you've only set it to `true`, it will use the post type name as the archive slug, so your archive is located at:

```
mysite.com/product/
```

To change that, simply set it to the slug you want to use:

```
'has_archive' => 'products'
```

Then your archive will be located where you want it:

```
mysite.com/products/
```

Remember to visit your `Settings > Permalinks` page after making changes that effect permalinks, this will flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: I knew it couldn't be that difficult. Thank you Milo.

Comment: Milo, how would I then go about making subcategories for a custom post type? If for example I wanted an archive page for all the electronic products, book products etc. or any other product categories I might dream up? And what would be the URL of that archive page?

Comment: those would be taxonomy term archives, and those URLs are set by the `rewrite` argument when you [register a taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). If you want to use the built in category taxonomy instead of a custom taxonomy, you need to [add some code to get your product post type to show up on those pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47083/4771).

Comment: I see. I've added the rewrite argument now but when I click 'view' in the taxonomy admin page it takes me to the correct url www.mysite/products/books but no entries appear. It shows I've added some to the category (a number appears next to it) but no posts appear...

Comment: that is strange. are you sure it's the same taxonomy you've added products to? in your post type registration, you're associating the built in category and tag taxonomies to your post type, but then you also associate the `product_category` custom taxonomy to products via the taxonomy registration code. you also don't set any name arguments, so it will show up as "Tags" in the admin UI, which may be confusing.

Comment: yeah, you're telling me. I don't get it. I posted my updated code in my question if you'd like to take a look at it. Does it have anything to do with the way my permalinks are set up? I have them set as custom /%category%/%postname%

Comment: ok, two issues - the slug `type` is used by WordPress for post formats, you have to use a different slug for your taxonomy. the 2nd issue is the `exclude_from_search` argument in `register_post_type`, that prevents your products from showing up on taxonomy pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you use custom taxonomy post type, you can create `taxonomy-your-taxonomy-post-type.php`.

Let's say for your url `www.mysite.com/products`, your must create `taxonomy-products.php`

Comment: Ok, I remember seeing that in some forms. But what do I put in that taxonomy-products.php document?

Comment: It is ok, you can add category.php code to taxonomy-products.php file. I think that would works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 First of all add custom post type `News` with Taxonomy `category_news`.

```
function news() {
        $args = array(
            'label' => 'News',
            'singular_label' => 'news',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar',
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        );
        register_post_type('news',$args);

    }
add_action('init', 'news');
register_taxonomy('category_news', array('news'), array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'News category','show_admin_column' => true, 'singular_label' => 'News category', 'rewrite' => true));
```

Step:2 Add template of category page using `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`... In our example it should be `taxonomy-category_news.php`