# How to add custom post types to normal category pages

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want to have a custom post type, named `event`, listed with normal posts in the category pages.

I have managed to add categories easily to the custom post type with this:

```
add_action('init', 'add_category_boxes');
add_action('plugins_loaded','add_category_boxes');
function add_category_boxes()
{
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'event');
}
```

This displays the category checkboxes in wp-admin and works fine.
I have then followed the approach [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/adding-categories-across-posts-and-custom-post-types) (also suggested elsewhere), as follows:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) 
{
  if(is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) 
  {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('post','event');

    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
  }
}
```

But the posts of type `event` still don't come up in the respective category pages.
What could be the reason for this? Do I need to add anything else?

The `event` post types are actually coming from the Events Manager plugin. I don't know if there is something special about these which is stopping them from being displayed in the category pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have one or two problems here

- `is_category()` should be object of `$query` in your example code
- `get_query_var('post_type')` will always return false on a category page AFAIK, so that code is totally unnecessary
- Just a tip, when using `pre_get_posts` with any type of archive, also check for non admin pages as your back end will also be affected by this change

You can try something like this

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_category() ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', array( 'post','event' ) );
    }
});
```

Comment: For the `is_category()` I was referring to this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category. Its not a method of the `$query`.

Comment: You need to make it one in `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I solved by passing the `nav_menu_item` to the `$post_type` for the menu to appear properly. In your case would be:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) 
{
  if(is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) 
  {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', $post_type);
    else
        $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', 'post', 'event' );

    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating taxonomy like category & tags for custom post type use `register_taxonomy` wordpress function

Refer this wordpress codex for [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Comment: The problem is not related to `register_taxonomy`. As I mentioned above, the checkboxes for the categories already display fine in the admin screen when editing the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve the issue:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type( $query ) {
  if( is_category() &&  $query->is_main_query() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'event'));
      return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how does this differ from my answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen The problem was that in both my original method and in yours we are both using `is_main_query()`. For some reason when I removed that, the custom posts appeared as I wanted. The `nav_menu_item` is required however when the `is_main_query()` is removed, because otherwise menus stop working.

Comment: You know this will effect all oother custom queries, even widgets if you remove `is_main_query()`. How does the page look that you need to modify. If it is a custom query, then you should not be using `pre_get_posts`

Comment: From what you are saying, there is another bigger issue somewhere

Comment: It seems to be working fine so far. What should I look out for?

Comment: Well, it is difficult to say. Something is breaking your main query. Are you by any change using `query_posts` or any other custom query that is not resetted with `wp_reset_postdata()` or any other pre_get_posts instance that is incorrectly used

Comment: Not really, at least not that I know of unless some plugin is doing it. All I have is the usual loop. But it IS working now. Unless the problem was being caused by some weird caching issue and I thought that this change solved it... I could try putting in the `is_main_query()` check again and see.

Comment: This is on your category.php template. I would start looking at plugins and caches. I would suggest to clear out all caches. Try one of the bundled themes just for a test. To be really honest, I would really try to get the root of this.

Comment: I think it must have been a caching issue (I use W3TC). I added the `$query->is_main_query()` check back and cleared the caches of W3TC and it still working fine. I don't have anything special in `category.php`, its just the loop.

Comment: Great, that is your problem. I would suggest that you set yourself up with a test installation without any cache plugins to properly test code.

Comment: Hi, I added meta_query to it,but on adding meta query, the menu item is turning off ... No menu links are being shown .. Here is the code I added before return $query.
$query->set('meta_query', [
            [
                'key' => 'status',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ]);